# Prevent indent when formatting CSS

Tags: css, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

In Visual Studio 2013 when I format my CSS code (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) it will sometimes indent my CSS properties into a hierarchy.

For example:

```css
.a { color:red; }
.a .b {color:blue; }
```

Becomes:

```css
.a {
  color:red;
}

   .a .b {
     color:blue;
   }
```

When I would prefer:

```css
.a {
  color:red;
}

.a .b {
  color:blue;
}
```

Is there a way of modifying Visual Studio to prevent this indentation?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Yes, you can set a preference for this from the Tools, Options menu.

Drill down in `Text Editor` to `CSS`, and under `Advanced`, turn `Hierarchical Indentation` off:

[image]

Comment: This change takes immediate effect, but if your css file is open with a split screen when you make the change it will only take effect in the top panel.  Just un-split or close and reopen to remedy.  (VS2017)